# Resuscitating motherboard

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a strange problem going on.
I received a not working PC to fix and I'm trying to revive it.
I'm close to trash away everything but before to do that I wonder if somebody can give me some hints.

- CPU Intel Core i7-3770 3.40GHz-3.90GHz Ivy Bridge Quad-Core Processor LGA1155 8MB 77W
- Motherboard Asus P8H61-M LX2/CM6731
- 2 4Gbyte DDR3 RAM

Symptoms :

- powering up (LED on motherboard on - fan starts)
- no video signal
- no sign of work

It did stop to work one day without any apparent cause.
No thunderstorms or other events that could explain the problem.
When I received the PC, somebody (don't know who) apparently diagnosed the problem to be the motherboard.
So a new identical motherboard was bought and CPU and memory were moved on the new mobo (I didn't do that).
However same identical result. No activity, totally dead.

So this is what I did receive. A dead PC with a new mobo, old CPU and old memory.
Assuming the mobo to be new, the total lack of activity made me suspect a fried CPU.
I did attach a speaker to the mobo and no activity with the original CPU.
So I did buy an identical CPU and changed it.

The speaker did come on with 3 short beeps.
I did reset the RTC and tried again.
This time the speaker come out with 4 short beeps.
Still no video activity.  The fans are working.

So far I did all the tests with anything connected, no HD/CD, only a keyboard and video (on the motherboard).
Looking around for the diagnostic beeps, another candidate for the problem was the memory.
So I did buy a new set of 2 4Gbyte DDR3.

Nothing.
So to sum up :

- new motherboard
- new CPU
- new memory

And still is not working !!!! totally dead !
I'm quite lost.
I also used a diagnostic board I had around and it ends with an error code 55 14, not really useful though also if looking for some documentation suggest some memory problem, bank 1.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks !!!
This is driving me crazy !!

Steve

Comment: You’ve swapped everything but the power supply. Double check all your work and make sure you have everything hooked up right. It would be a big waste of time if the new equipment wasn’t working because of a small mistake.  After that, try a different power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a new power supply?

It is possible that the part of the power supply that runs the fans works, but the internal switching unit may have failed so that it is not supply proper voltages to the motherboard.